# Error in application-context-security.xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a project but i am getting a error  "The prefix "context" for element "context:component-scan" is not bound" in side the xml file 
my file code is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

 <!--Here is i am getting error "The prefix "context" for element "context:component-scan" is not bound."-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="tudu.security"/>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<HTTP>
    <INTERCEPT-URL PATTERN="/AJAX/**" ACCESS="ROLE_USER" />
    <INTERCEPT-URL PATTERN="/TUDU/WELCOME" ACCESS="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <INTERCEPT-URL PATTERN="/TUDU/RECOVERPASSWORD" ACCESS="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <INTERCEPT-URL PATTERN="/TUDU/REGISTER" ACCESS="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <INTERCEPT-URL PATTERN="/TUDU/ADMIN" ACCESS="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <INTERCEPT-URL PATTERN="/TUDU/**" ACCESS="ROLE_USER" />
    <INTERCEPT-URL PATTERN="/SERVLET/**" ACCESS="ROLE_USER" />

    <FORM-LOGIN LOGIN-PROCESSING-URL="/TUDU/LOGIN" LOGIN-PAGE="/TUDU/WELCOME"
        AUTHENTICATION-FAILURE-URL="/TUDU/WELCOME?AUTHENTICATION=FAILURE"
        DEFAULT-TARGET-URL="/TUDU/LISTS" ALWAYS-USE-DEFAULT-TARGET="TRUE" />

    <REMEMBER-ME KEY="TUDUROCKS" />
    <LOGOUT LOGOUT-URL="/TUDU/LOGOUT" />
</HTTP>

<AUTHENTICATION-MANAGER ALIAS="AUTHENTICATIONMANAGER">
    <AUTHENTICATION-PROVIDER USER-SERVICE-REF="USERDETAILSSERVICE" />
</AUTHENTICATION-MANAGER>
```

Comment: you don't have xsd for `context` like: `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`

Comment: You have space before starting tag of xml ...remove space it will run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You xml namespace need some changes

1. You are missing the context namespace
2. Your default namespace is beans and it looks like you prefer the security as the default
3. If your not using beans as default name space you should add the prefix beans: to the root element
4. I prefer keeping xml names and attributes in lower case

This should work.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!--Here is i am getting error "The prefix "context" for element "context:component-scan" 
        is not bound." -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="tudu.security" />

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/AJAX/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/WELCOME" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/RECOVERPASSWORD" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/REGISTER" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/ADMIN" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/SERVLET/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <form-login login-processing-url="/TUDU/LOGIN" login-page="/TUDU/WELCOME"
            authentication-failure-url="/TUDU/WELCOME?AUTHENTICATION=FAILURE"
            default-target-url="/TUDU/LISTS" always-use-default-target="true" />

        <remember-me key="TUDUROCKS" />
        <logout logout-url="/TUDU/LOGOUT" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="AUTHENTICATIONMANAGER">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="USERDETAILSSERVICE" />
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

I am using the spring config editor provided with [STS](http://spring.io/tools/sts) which make my life easier.

Comment: yeah i am also using stc but i replace my code with the code you provided but i am getting the same error along with "cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'." this ..

Comment: I tried this in the editor and it works fine. Just cut and past the entire beans element above under <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> . Make sure no extra spaces. Then hit CTRL-SHIF-F. save it and reopen with "Open With"-> Spring Config Editor

Comment: thanks @Haim its working there were some version problem i fixed it now it working fine thanks..

Comment: now i am getting one more error at <global-method-security ------/>     like this "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'global-method-security'. One of 
 '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/
 beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is 
 expected."

Answer (score 1):

there may be some problem with namespaces ...
what you have done untill now is correct ..... but just you need to change one thing 
ie.

**put security in your default name space...**

just copy this line :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
```

and past it inside **bean opening tag**

or you can also use prefixes for all security tags like :

```
<security:http>
```

Comment: <security:http>
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/AJAX/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
  </security:http>

Answer (score 0):

this is working correctly..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="tudu.security" />

<security:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" />

<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/AJAX/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/WELCOME"
        access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/RECOVERPASSWORD"
        access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/REGISTER"
        access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/ADMIN"
        access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/TUDU/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/SERVLET/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />

    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/TUDU/LOGIN"
        login-page="/TUDU/WELCOME" authentication-failure-url="/TUDU/WELCOME?AUTHENTICATION=FAILURE"
        default-target-url="/TUDU/LISTS" always-use-default-target="true" />

    <security:remember-me key="TUDUROCKS" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/TUDU/LOGOUT" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="AUTHENTICATIONMANAGER">
<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="USERDETAILSSERVICE"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```